# What does the command-line option "-A" in the ssh command do?

Tags: command-line, ssh

As the title mentions, what does `-A` do? If i run `man ssh` there is no part which explains this option.

Additional, whats the optionname for this parameter for a ssh config file?
Where can I find a mapping between thoose cmd arguments and the configfile option names?

Comment: [https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-A](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-A)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html), which for me lists this option as the fifth:

```
-A  Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.
    This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

    Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution. Users with the
    ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host
    (for the agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent
    through the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot
    obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform
    operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate
    using the identities loaded into the agent.
```

See [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for the config file option names, without having dug into it I think you want `ForwardAgent` here.

Comment: thanks, shame on me, didnt saw this part in the man file :(

Comment: @mr.void When viewing a man page, you can press `/` to search, type something (e.g. `-A`) and press Enter. Every visible occurance of the typed characters will be highlighted, and the viewer will jump to the first occurance. Press `n` to move to the next one or `N` to move to the previous one. The search pattern is actually a regular expression, but for simple searches, just typing what you are searching for is sufficient.